# Pivoting on two comma delimited columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I am struggling with this one, I have two fields in a table one contains the header names, the other contains the results

eg,

```
ResultID  TestID   MemberID    HeaderDefinition             ResultDefinition
1         1        1           Minutes Exercised|KJ Burnt   60|900
2         2        1           Height|Weight|BMI            142|94|35
3         1        2           Minutes Exercised|KJ Burnt   70|1000
4         2        3           Height|Weight|BMI            150|60|20
```

What I would like to do is pass in a TestID and see it Pivoted on the header

eg. Test 1

```
MemberID     Minutes Exercised    KJ Burnt
1            60                   900
2            70                   1000
```

eg. Test 2

```
MemberID     Height     Weight    BMI
1            142        94        35
3            150        60        20
```

I have looked at all the standard Pivoting examples and dynamic data but it works on using the same field, I need one field to define the headers and another to define the results and not sure how to marry them up into the examples above, any help would be appreciated.

I can't alter the structure of the data by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it only ever those two Tests, or can there be others with a variable number of "columns" (|-split) in the Definition columns?

Comment: First thing to do: Beat up your DB administrator. And if he asks why, you say "first normal form"

Comment: Hey Sean, It could be a variable number of columns in the definition columns, I have no idea how many there are, this is just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PIVOT will work; that's for switching columns to rows / vice versa. In your example, you have (a variable number of) columns within a single column, separated by a pipe character (|).

So you need to do some preparation work first. This preparation work depends on how many different tests you have, and how many different columns there can be inside that single column. If it's just the two tests with the 2 or 3 columns in the example above, then you could "hard-code" a query or two that will extract the data. If it's more variable than that, you'll probably need a cursor or temp table to do more complex preparation work.

So, here's an example using a hard-coded set of 2 queries, you would have to make a few minor adjustments to use your table data, instead of the variables:

```
declare @TestID int, @ResultDefinition varchar(100), @MemberID int
set @TestID = 1
set @MemberID = 1

if @TestID = 1 begin

    set @ResultDefinition = '60|900'

    select  @MemberID, 
        LEFT(@ResultDefinition, CHARINDEX('|',  @ResultDefinition)-1) AS [Minutes Exercised],
        SUBSTRING(@ResultDefinition, CHARINDEX('|',  @ResultDefinition)+1, LEN(@ResultDefinition)) AS [KJ Burnt]
    --from  tblResults 
    --where TestID = @TestID

end else begin

    set @ResultDefinition = '142|94|35'

    select  @MemberID, 
        LEFT(@ResultDefinition, CHARINDEX('|',  @ResultDefinition)-1) AS [Height],
        LEFT(SUBSTRING(@ResultDefinition, charindex('|', @ResultDefinition) + 1, LEN(@ResultDefinition) ), charindex('|', SUBSTRING(@ResultDefinition, charindex('|', @ResultDefinition) + 1, LEN(@ResultDefinition) ))-1) as [Weight],
        reverse(left(reverse(@ResultDefinition),  CHARINDEX('|', reverse(@ResultDefinition))-1)) as [BMI]
    --from  tblResults 
    --where TestID = @TestID

end
```

If it's more complicated than that, then... I actually don't even want to go there! :) It's going to involve building a table structure dynamically and then populating it with the relevant data, then selecting the contents.

Maybe someone else has a more elegant solution though...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a `PIVOT` if you also implement a Split function similar to this:

**Split Function**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end;
```

Then if you know the values that you want to turn into columns, then you can hard-code the values using a static pivot:

```
select *
from
(
  select h.memberid,
    h.cols,
    r.results
  from
  (
    select t1.resultid,
      t1.testid,
      t1.memberid, 
      h.items cols,
      row_number() over(partition by memberid order by memberid) rn
    from table1 t1
    cross apply dbo.split(t1.headerdefinition, '|') h
    where t1.testid = 1
  ) h
  left join
  (
    select t1.resultid,
      t1.testid,
      t1.memberid, 
      r.items results,
      row_number() over(partition by memberid order by memberid) rn
    from table1 t1
    cross apply dbo.split(t1.resultdefinition, '|') r
    where t1.testid = 1
  ) r
    on h.memberid = r.memberid
    and h.rn = r.rn
) x
pivot
(
  max(results)
  for cols in ([Minutes Exercised], [KJ Burnt])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/881b2/36)

But I am going to guess that you will want to use a dynamic `PIVOT` since you will have a different number of columns for each of the entries.  Your code will be similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @testid int = 2

select @cols = 
      STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(x.cols) 
             from
             (
               select h.items cols,
                row_number() over(partition by memberid order by memberid) rn
               from table1 t1
               cross apply dbo.split(t1.headerdefinition, '|') h
               where t1.testid = @testid
             ) x
             group by cols, rn
             order by rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'SELECT memberid, ' + @cols + ' from 
     (
        select h.memberid,
          h.cols,
          r.results
        from
        (
          select t1.resultid,
            t1.testid,
            t1.memberid, 
            h.items cols,
            row_number() over(partition by memberid order by memberid) rn
          from table1 t1
          cross apply dbo.split(t1.headerdefinition, ''|'') h
          where t1.testid = '+ cast(@testid as varchar(10)) +'
        ) h
        left join
        (
          select t1.resultid,
            t1.testid,
            t1.memberid, 
            r.items results,
            row_number() over(partition by memberid order by memberid) rn
          from table1 t1
          cross apply dbo.split(t1.resultdefinition, ''|'') r
          where t1.testid = '+ cast(@testid as varchar(10)) +'
        ) r
          on h.memberid = r.memberid
          and h.rn = r.rn
      ) x
      pivot
      (
        max(results)
        for cols in ('+@cols+')
      ) p'

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59944/1)

Then depending on the `@testid` you pass your results will be either:

```
| MEMBERID | MINUTES EXERCISED | KJ BURNT |
-------------------------------------------
|        1 |                60 |      900 |
|        2 |                70 |     1000 |
```

Or

```
| MEMBERID | HEIGHT | WEIGHT | BMI |
------------------------------------
|        1 |    142 |     94 |  35 |
|        3 |    150 |     60 |  20 |
```